# Solr could not index my table from mysql

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-10.04, solr, jdbc

I have ubuntu server and mysql version 5.1.41-3ubuntu12.10-log.
i need to run solr on my webserver. i have installed lucidworks-enterprise-installer-1.7 and mysql-connector-java-5.1.17-bin.jar on the webserver already. but i can't build the index for solr and it keeps giving me **Total Documents Failed** tag with number all of my records

```
<str name="Total Documents Failed">15511</str>
```

any idea of what might cause this?
Thanks

Comment: You will have to install the JDBC driver into your web application or the container / server running it, not on the MySQL server side. Can you give more details on what kind of web apps you are running and on which kind of server?

Comment: the question has been edited

Answer (score 0):

i have fixed it.
there was

```
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="id" omitNorms="true" stored="true" type="string"/>
```

in the schema.xml.
i just commented it as there is another tag for id which is

```
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
```